# PHP5-FPM goes to 100% cpu usage and doesn't go down

Tags: php, nginx, cpu-usage

Please check the following image:

Output of: `htop -u www-data`

[image: htop -u www-data]

My current configuration of `pool.d/www.conf` is:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 4
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 50
```

It's a 4 core cpu with 8gb ram. Ram usage is considerably less. If I have set max_children = 4, does that mean it there can be only 4 processes? (In screenshot, there are more than 8 php-fpm processes)

And sometimes, it just stays at 100% in all 4 cores and website gives a 502 error till I restart php5-fpm.

Comment: Have you checked your code for infinite loops? For setting the amount of max children see for example http://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you find a fix in the meantime?